# Laravel Eloquent Eager Loading with belongsToMany too slow

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, pagination

I have `users` that can belong to `groups` in a many to many relationship.  I'm trying to retrieve (**paginate**) users with all the groups they belong to. This works fine, but when I have 1000+ users, things get really slow, even though I'm only paginating 25 to 50 at a time. On my User model:

```
public function groups()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\UserGroup', 'group_user', 'user_id', 'group_id');
}
```

My query is:

```
User::with('groups')->paginate(50);
```

So if I have around 50 users total in the database (MySQL), everything is super fast (<= 300ms).  But when I add 1000, even though I'm still only paginating up to 50 per page, it crawls (~3 seconds).

### EDIT

Actually normal request with around 50 TOTAL users is ~100ms, not 300ms.

Comment: I would say 300ms is not fast enough for 50 users. Do you have foreign key index set properly on database?

Comment: Sorry that was the total time including other requests.  I misread it.  It's more like 100-150ms.

Comment: You can try to analyse the query logs to see what queries are taking long, and try to check on the database why they are taking long. Add `\DB::enableQueryLog();` at the beginning of your script, and then `var_dump(\DB::getQueryLog());` at the end to see the queries.

Comment: also make sure you set index that references the primary key on each table in the migration

Comment: I have foreign keys pointing to primary keys for all tables involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Thiago Barcala's comment, I was able to analyze the query logs with:

```
\DB::enableQueryLog();
// perform query...
var_dump(\DB::getQueryLog());
```

And I found the issue. Basically, I had a `with` attribute on my groups model:

```
protected $with = [
    'features',
    'users'
];
```

So I have a bunch of users being returned, and they're getting their groups returned, and each of those groups are returning all of the users in them.  So I was getting like 10MB worth of data returned all because of this relation including more relations.  I removed the `with` and all is well.